# How do I make the first half of the values of an array become keys, and the other half to become values of those keys?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, higher-order-functions

I have the following:

`const array = [{value: 'banana'}, {value: 'apple'}, {value: 'yellow'}, {value: 'red'}]`

I need the following:

`const result = [{banana: 'yellow'}, {apple: 'red'}];`

Is there a way to create result from the array, using loops or higher-order-functions in JavaScript?

Comment: Post the **[JavaScript]** that uses **[higher order functions]** that **[loop]** through **[arrays]** of **[objects]** as a [mcve]. We will fix it but don't expect us to write the whole thing for you.

Comment: My question is not very specific because I have already tried using reduce, filter, map, forEach, even vanila for,  but couldn't get the result I needed...

Comment: Great, let's see it so we won't be asking so many questions and second guessing one another.

Comment: Please let me know what is the result of trying this: `const lenBy2 = Math.floor(array.length / 2); const resObj = Object.fromEntries(array.map(({ value }, idx) => (idx < lenBy2 ? [ value, array[idx + lenBy2]?.value ] : [] )).filter(x => x.length == 2)); console.log(resObj);`. If it meets your expectation, I shall explain the steps. BTW, for the benefit of other members: this is not an **answer**. It is merely seeking clarification on what is the impact of trying something.

Comment: @jsN00b, yeah, this is it!!! I just need to understand it now hehehe.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.prototype.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap):

```js
const flatMapToEntry = (key, index, array) => {
  const length = array.length / 2;
  if (index >= length) {
    return [];
  }
  const value = array[index + length];
  return [{ [key]: value }];
};
const result = array.map(o => o.value).flatMap(flapMapToEntry);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer using the same logic provided in the comment. This has relevant descriptions to help understand better.

```js
const getMyObject = arr => {
  // first compuate the half-length "lenBy2" of given array
  const lenBy2 = Math.floor(arr.length / 2);
  
  // return the "result" as an object
  return Object
    .fromEntries(                 // generate object from key-value pairs below
      arr.map(                    // iterate "arr" to obtain key-value pairs
        ({ value }, idx) => (     // get the index "idx" and de-structure to access "value"
          idx < lenBy2            // if index less than half-length "lenBy2"
          ? [                     // return key-value pair as a 2-element array
            value,                // [ "banana", "yellow" ], for example
            arr[idx + lenBy2]?.value
          ]
          : []                    // if index >= half-length, return empty array
        )
      ).filter(                   // filter key-value pairs to retain only non-empty ones
        x => x.length == 2
      )
    );
};

// below are steps only to generate results for various test cases
// the original array from the question
const array1 = [{value: 'banana'}, {value: 'apple'}, {value: 'yellow'}, {value: 'red'}];

// test-case 2 - an array with 3 pairs
const array2 = [
  {value: 'banana'}, {value: 'apple'}, {value: 'tomato'},
  {value: 'yellow'}, {value: 'green'}, {value: 'red'}
];

// mismatched array where the fruit "orange" has no matching color
const array3 = [
  {value: 'banana'}, {value: 'apple'}, {value: 'orange'},
  {value: 'yellow'}, {value: 'red'}
];

// mismatched array where the color "orange" has no matching fruit
const array4 = [
  {value: 'banana'}, {value: 'apple'},
  {value: 'yellow'}, {value: 'red'}, {value: 'orange'}
];

// iterate over the various test case arrays &
// console.log the result
[array1, array2, array3, array4].forEach((arr, idx) =>
  console.log(
    `\n***---> test case ${idx + 1} <---***\n`,
    'given array:  ', JSON.stringify(arr),
    '\n\nresult object:  \n', getMyObject(arr),
    '\n ***---> end of result <---*** \n\n'
  )
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

Feel free to post questions in comments, in case it is unclear how the above works.